# Woo-Commerce theme showing Original images on category page and not thumbnails

Tags: image, woocommerce

Using the IDStore theme for Woo-commerce. I have grown to hate it but I'm committed at this point.

I recently upgraded the theme and now the category pages show the full size images (which are huge per customer request) instead of the thumbnails.

http://mariocontractlighting.com/product-category/luggage-racks/

I know this has something to do with getting thumbnail_id() instead of image_src() but not sure to make the change.

Need some help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

$url = etheme_get_image(false, $width, $height, $crop);
changed to 
$url = etheme_get_image(false, 200, 200);

It was that simple but located nowhere in the theme documentation.